# How to stop automatically converting section titles to uppercase [revtex4-2]

Tags: titles, revtex, uppercase

Is there a way to stop automatic uppercasing for section titles (without using \lowercase{} for every word that should be in lowercase)?

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,bbm,xcolor}
```

This problem exists for all document classes under revtex4-2.

Comment: Please post a full example. You probably have some formatting in your template or class.

Answer (score 1):

The APS “substyle” has

```
\def\@hangfrom@section#1#2#3{\@hangfrom{#1#2}\MakeTextUppercase{#3}}%
\def\@hangfroms@section#1#2{#1\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}%
```

which means that APS *wants* uppercased titles.

You might redefine the commands to not apply `\MakeTextUppercase`:

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,bbm,xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\@hangfrom@section#1#2#3{\@hangfrom{#1#2}#3}%\MakeTextUppercase{#3}}%
\def\@hangfroms@section#1#2{#1#2}%\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{This is a section title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't complain if you paper is rejected for being nonconformant to the house style.